# Ссылка на ссылке — как нажать на одну, не активируя родительскую?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет!

Кейс (ссылка на ссылке):

```
<a href="#1" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
    <div class="n1"></div>
    <div class="n2"></div>
    <div class="n3"></div>
    <div><input onclick="#2"></div>
</a>
```

По умолчанию, при нажатии на input активируется и родительская ссылка #1 и js-действие #2.
Какие CSS-свойства надо прописать у слоев, чтобы при нажатии на input активировалось только js-действие #2 без активации ссылки #1?
При этом условие - при нажатии на n1,n2,n3 родительская ссылка #1 не должна перестать активироваться.

Спасибо.

Comment: @KamilFo, в спецификации HTML есть [пара отдельных строчек](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2) про то, что вложенные ссылки запрещены уголовным кодексом полиции интернета. Но вообще достаточно, чтобы вызванное js-действие делало возврат false (`return false;`).

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/AwN4J/ как то так, хотя странный подход, в строчный а вкладывать кучу блочных див, как то не валидно что ли )))))

```js
var a = document.getElementById('aa');
   a.onclick = function fun(){alert('ok');return false}
```

```html
<a href="#1" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
  <div class="n1">a</div>
  <div class="n2">s</div>
  <div class="n3">d</div>
  <div><input onclick="#2" id="aa">ss</div>
 </a>
```